# How to add 'WITH READ ONLY' constraint in views in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have created a simple view and have forgotten to add WITH READ ONLY while creating the view.
Now I want to alter the view and add WITH READ ONLY option. What will be the query for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
alter view x read only;
```

was added in [11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4004.htm#SQLRF01104), but unfortunately only for *editioning views*.
So there is a chance that in some future version this will be extended to regular views:)

Until that use simple create or replace view

```
create or replace view x as 
select * from dual /* your query */
with read only;
```

or

```
create or replace view x as 
select * from dual /* your query */
with check option;
```

Comment: What about 'with check option' ?

Comment: @Azeem I added an example

Comment: Really appreciate it.